# wordpress 3.4.2 + wp_nav_menu + chunk theme not working

Tags: menus

I'm trying to create a page for each of the categories i got in my blog and it should appear on the menu i got in Chunk theme.

the idea is to have a link to each of the categories which would guide you to something like this 'http://blog.direktio.com/category/business-intelligence/'

so I found out that wp_nav_menu is the one that creates the menus, and that it has a parameter named

`'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'`

which allows me to add other stuff to the wrapping of the menu created by the function..

so te idea is to do something like this:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'items_wrap' => 'sssssss %3$s' ) ); ?>`

so I would get a menu with some 'sssss' and then the usual list items....

but hey... it doesn't show 'sssss' at all... so the question here is why is this parameter `items_wrap` not working according to [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

thanks in advance for any help

edit: as requested here is a [link to the theme](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/chunk/) in question, hadn't include that since it is one of the default themes anyway... i don't think there is a real problem with the them per se, im reading wp_nav_menu docs (more) thouroughly now

edit2: found an answer.... lemme write it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching around a little, I found that (as you may have noticed) I'm a newbie in wordpress.... there is no need to screw with code to do this

I had never seen the "Menus" option in the administration side bar.... so ... go there and create a new menu...

from which you can put custom links, links to the categories, to the pages you already have and when you are happy with the result, just save it, and in the `Theme locations` little widget at your left, select which menu you want to go in which position in your theme.... and thats it....

if further ilustration is required ask me